# Redirect a website url to another website url - GoDaddy

Tags: amazon-ec2, plesk, amazon-route53

I have a domain let say `xyz.com`, and I have an internal URL like this, `xyz.com/testUrl`. I need to redirect this URL (`xyz.com/testUrl`) to another web site URL.(which is URL like this `ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3001/employee`).

Now, whenever someone hits `xyz.com/testUrl` , he should be redirected to `ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3001/employee`.

I am using goDadddy hosting.

Comment: What url do you want seen in the browser? Also see [this](https://www.godaddy.com/help/redirect-urls-with-your-hosting-account-5120) from godaddy

Comment: The domain name like `xyz.com` is handled by DNS (Godaddy). The port (like the implicit port 80 in `/testUrl` and port 3001 in `:3001/employee`) are handled by your server, or possibly something like a load balancer. The path `/testUrl` and `/employee` are handled by the web server, like Apache or Nginx. You have to configure the appropriate piece to perform the appropriate redirect.

Comment: Also why is the question tagged with Plesk (do you have that installed and running on your EC2 server?), and Route53 (aren't you using Godaddy for DNS?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create .htaccess file in web root of xyz.com with content:

```
Redirect 302 /testUrl xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3001/employee
```

Answer (score -1):

This will do the required work.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/xyz.com/testUrl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView method() {
    return new ModelAndView("ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3001/employee");
}
```